# SQL Create view with declare in SQL server

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssis

In SQL query i have multiple declare variables its working fine but i want to convert this into view but getting error. below is script kindly help me convert this into view. Many thanks. I have tried to tabled value function and using function inside not able to succeed.

```
--create view TEST_VIEW AS 
DECLARE
@COL1 @COL2 @COL3 
@COL4 
@COL5 
@COL6 int,
@COL7 nvarchar(1000),
@COL8 int,
@COL9 nvarchar(100),
@COL10 nvarchar(100)
DECLARE 
@temp TABLE (  @COL1 @COL2 @COL3 
@COL4 
@COL5 ,
COL6 int,
COL7 nvarchar(1000),
COL8 int,
COL9 nvarchar(100),
COL10 nvarchar(100));
DECLARE cursor_Update CURSOR fast_forward
FOR select  @COL1 @COL2 @COL3 
@COL4 
@COL5 
,COL6
,COL7
,COL8
,COL9
,COL10 from G.FACT_G_DEPLOYMENTS;
OPEN cursor_Update;

FETCH NEXT FROM cursor_Update INTO   @COL1 @COL2 @COL3 
@COL4 
@COL5 @COL6,
@COL7,@COL8,@COL9,@COL10;

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN
Declare @TotalMonth int;
If (@COL10 is null)
Begin
set @TotalMonth = DATEDIFF(MONTH,convert(date,@COL4 ,103),GETDATE())
End
else
Begin

PRINT @COL10;
set @TotalMonth = DATEDIFF(MONTH,@COL4,CAST(@COL10 AS DATETIME))
End

DECLARE @Counter INT
SET @Counter=0;
WHILE ( @Counter <= @TotalMonth)
BEGIN

INSERT INTO @temp VALUES( @COL1,@COL2,@COL3,DATEADD(MONTH,@Counter, convert(date,@COL4 ,103)),@COL5,@COL6,
@COL7,@COL8,@COL9,@COL10)

SET @Counter = @Counter + 1;
END

FETCH NEXT FROM cursor_Update INTO @COL1,COL6,
@COL7,@COL8,@COL9,@COL10;
END;
CLOSE cursor_Update;
DEALLOCATE cursor_Update;
SELECT * FROM @temp;
```

Comment: You don't want a *view* you want a *stored procedure*. Fwiw your cursor is also completely unecessary.

Comment: Rewrite this piece of code in a simple SELECT query and it will solve your problem

Comment: A `VIEW` must is defined by a **single** `SELECT` statement; nothing more, nothing less. No `DECLARE`s, no `INSERT`s, just a `SELECT` (CTE's are included as that is an expression) Perhaps, you want a **inline** table value function. Most certainly there are multiple flaws above. For example, you have `CURSOR`, something that is almost *always* the wrong choice (I can count the number of times you should using a `CURSOR` on one hand).

Comment: `@Col2,@Col3,@Col4,@Col5` are all not declared, where are they coming from? You need a tally table or tally function here, not a cursor. @Stu there is no reason why this can't be a view. And is `@Col4` a date or a varchar?

Comment: @Charlieface i have updated the code.

Comment: @Larnu thanks for your input can you please provide some sample ?

Comment: So all of `@COL1 @COL2 @COL3 @COL4 @COL5 ` don;t actually exist in the table, and are fixed? You're not actually assigning them a value anywhere

Comment: Of what, an inline table value function? Have a look at the documentation, @Kum_R .

Comment: @Charlieface its from the table already existing

Comment: If you expect someone else to read your code, indent it properly. It's going to help you too in the long run.

Answer (score 0):

Cursors are slow and inefficient, and cannot be used in a view.

You can obviate the need for a cursor, by using a [tally/numbers table or function](https://sqlperformance.com/2021/01/t-sql-queries/number-series-solutions-1). I've used an on the fly CTE here, but there are other methods.

> It's unclear where some of the columns come from, due to syntax errors in your code, so I'm guessing a bit here.

```sql
CREATE OR ALTER VIEW TEST_VIEW AS 

WITH L0 AS (
    SELECT 1 c 
    FROM (VALUES(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),
                        (1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1)) AS D(c)
),
L1 AS (
    SELECT 1 c             -- good for 4096 rows
    FROM L0 A, L0 B, L0 C  -- add more cross-joins for more rows
)
Nums AS ( SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) AS rownum
          FROM L1
)
SELECT
  COL1,
  COL2,
  COL3,
  v2.Month,
  COL5,
  COL6,
  COL7,
  COL8,
  COL9,
  COL10
FROM G.FACT_G_DEPLOYMENTS dep
CROSS APPLY (VALUES(
    DATEDIFF(MONTH, @COL4, ISNULL(CAST(COL10 AS DATETIME), GETDATE()))
)) v1(TotalMonth)
CROSS APPLY (
    SELECT TOP (v.TotalMonth)
      Month = DATEADD(MONTH, rn - 1, convert(date,@COL4 ,103))
    FROM Nums
) v2;
```